# How should I handle a Stack Overflow question that requires a hardware solution?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope

Recently, I stepped on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792942/cant-see-any-signal-on-can-tx-line) that is about an allegedly faulty CAN transceiver code. After reading the question, I figured out that the user might be wrong in his way to verify that his code in working. He is testing the bus physically, with an oscilloscope. Considering this I was confident that the error was not in the code but in the measuring procedure, thus I asked him a hardware detail for the measuring. I was right and now I wonder how the question should handled:

- By answering the question by specifying what he forgot and how to correct it. But then it is off topic as it is a hardware solution. Moreover, his code could be wrong on top of that. But to mitigate the previous, he made a really common mistake and it is likely that the persons who would search this question en SO made the same mistake.
- By writing the solution into the comments section

Comment: If you're pretty sure it's a good question but the answer lies in the hardware, there's a third option. Modflag the question, and ask for it to be migrated to a site where it is on-topic (Electrical Engineering I guess), then answer it. Be sure to thoroughly check if it's on-topic there before modflagging. Writing full working answers in the comment section is never OK imo.

Comment: It'd probably be better if the OP lets go of this version of the question, finds a place more suitable for his problems and then asks a new question that is actually aimed at that target audience. The direction the comments have taken make it clear that this question is not for Stack Overflow

Comment: I think that if it is a software question that receives a hardware answer, it should stay in a software SE; that's where people will be searching if they're having the same issue.